# WLS - How to handle transaction

Tags: java, plsql, transactions, weblogic12c, jta

I am using Weblogic server where connection object is processing a transaction where the same connection instance is trying to use a different transaction then the existing transaction cannot complete and it throws transaction error, where the existing transaction is doing any commit/rollback operation and new transaction also uses commit/rollback operation from multiple procedures' using  same connection object. So Is there any way to use the same connection object should handle the session of particular transaction if it completes and then for new transaction new session should start to avoid this error

```
static {
    Context ctx = null;
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");


    LOGGER.debug("con outside " + conn);
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
           javax.sql.DataSource ds
                = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("jndi/mynonXADatasource");


        // UserTransaction tx = (UserTransaction) ctx.lookup("javax.transaction.UserTransaction");
         tx.begin();
         conn = ds.getConnection();
         conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static Connection getdatasourceconnection() {

    try {
        if (null == conn || conn.isClosed()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Getting new Connection");
            conn = getNewConnection();
            return conn;
        }
         conn = obtainConnection();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
    return conn;
}

private static Connection getNewConnection() {
    Context ctx = null;
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

    ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
     ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
    LOGGER.debug("con outside " + conn);

    Connection oraConn;        oraConn = null;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
        javax.sql.DataSource ds
                = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("jndi/mynonXADatasource"); 

        //UserTransaction userTransaction=(UserTransaction)ctx.lookup ("jndi/mynonXADatasource"); 
         conn = ds.getConnection();
       conn.setAutoCommit(false);

         LOGGER.debug("con inside " + conn);
        LOGGER.debug("context " + ctx);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}

public static void closeConnection(Connection conn) {

    try {
        if (null != conn) {
            conn.close();
            conn = null;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have 15 store procedure calls and using some DML/DDLs too and if I try to use same connection object I am getting transaction is in prepared phase /committed like that, where from store procedure there are commit operation are happening and if it takes time to process for a single process where another process(JMS) trying to use the same connection this transaction error is happening.Is there any way to use the same connection object without transaction failure instead of getting new connection every time please suggest.

Comment: Please include your code in the question. Better description than the current description.

Comment: I have added my code and below with the issue description

Answer (score 0):

> "I have 15 store procedure calls and using some DML/DDLs too ... where from store procedure there are commit operation are happening  "

This seems to be the crux of your problem. A Unit of Work should be a single transaction. However it seems your architecture builds a Unit of Work out of multiple transactions (in database realm a transaction is the activity between commits).

At the very least you need to skin your database layer with an API in which a Unit of Work is a single stored procedure. That stored procedure can call all the stored procs and execute all the DML necessary, but you have one database call which executes in one session. Once you've done that you can start to remove the commits from the lower level procedures and put transaction management where it belongs: the top of the call stack.